# Android Notify android phone from server

Tags: android, notifications, push, push-notification

I'm starting to work on the next step of my application which requires communication to a server, and more importantly being able to receive information from a server.

the concept is simple I want to be able from a server to tell the android device of a particular user that there is new informations (and xml file) to run in the application.

Since I'm completely ignorant in this area of programming my question is simple:

Can/How can I do that ?

Comment: See [Push Notifications in Android Platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)

Comment: thanks I had a feeling there was something like that just had no idea what the system was called. I think I can guess the answer to this but is it possible to launch a my activity from the notification ?

Comment: It's possible. The application is started when an Intent broadcast is recieved.

Comment: I believe the solution found on this link works on 1.6: http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Comment: Thanks I think that will help me a lot ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Push notifications (requires Android 2.2, and is currently only launched in Labs, and not universally available).
There's more information regarding Push over [here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/).