# Android Listener for remote application message

Tags: android, notifications, message, invitation

I'm developing a multiplayer game and I'm wondering how can I received a message from server, though the app doesn't run at that time.
For example, a player P1 wants to invite player P2 to play a game. On P2 phone, the game doesn't show on the screen currently. So how I can make the P2 Phone notify with P1's invitation?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Pham All you are looking for is [Push Notifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Here is a complete StackOverFlowpost "[achieving Push Notifications in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)"

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a task for cloud-to-device messaging!  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c2dm

Comment: Thanks Sparky. This's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks 100rabh, I found another solution for this: IBM's MQTT. Besides the Google's C2DM, this is really what I need. Thanks for all of your help.