# How to receive notification from web to android?

Tags: android, notifications

In the app I am developing, I need to receive notification from a php server without using c2dm. Help me anyone.

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform. There were several other techniques, except C2DM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have push notifications without C2DM.

The "other way" is to make the client pull the server for info every X minutes..which is by several reasons not very good.

Comment: then which method i wil use to receive notification from web

Comment: i already registered for C2DM. But i not yet receive registration in mail. the c2dm registration is done. but i not receive registration id in my mail. what i wil do. can u help me.