# How to push to iphone / android phones via php

Tags: php, android, iphone, push-notification, push

How can I use a php script to push to an iphone or android phone?

What I am thinking right now is to have a php script that will run every 15 minutes on a web server, check  if case x is satisfied, if not push a notification to the phone.

How can this be accomplished if its even possible?  If not what approach should I take to achieving this? Any links or break downs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: look at http://urbanairship.com/

Comment: What about something that doesn't require a 3rd party application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the notifications yourself, you'll need to read up on sending push notifications to each platform. [This SO question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1378671/643383) address sending notifications on Android. [This article](http://vxtindia.com/blog/push-notifications-for-your-iphone-app-with-php-and-ubuntu/) is one of many in addition to Apple's docs that explain the process for iOS. If you use a third party service like Urban Airship, you'll need to look at [that API](http://urbanairship.com/resources/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, how about using an existing tool such as [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)? They provide a [PHP library](https://github.com/urbanairship/php-library) as well as [a super-simple example using PHP's `libcurl`](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/91072-simple-push-using-php-amp-the-api).

Comment: Last time I looked it up, it required a 3rd party app as well which is an approach my team wanted to see if we could do with out

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup your own server for push notifications, you should take a look at [Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/). It's a PHP library for push notifications which is very easy to set up and customize.

Comment: Thank you, would this work for android as well?  I only see iOS on it

Comment: Ups, I'm sorry. I totally missed that you wanted to push to Android phones to. As far as I know, Easy APNS only works for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

[Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/android/c2dm/) is used to push notifications to Android devices. You can develop server part yourself or use existing service such as [Urbanairship](http://urbanairship.com/). It allows you to send pushes to both Android and iPhone but you'll have to pay for it.