# Push Notifications and Android activities

Tags: android, notifications, push

I am a newbie in android and push notifications and i have built a PHP page to send such push messages. as long as the app is in foreground - i can detect and show an alert dialog.  when onReceive() is called. when i press the "Back" button , the app (i guess) closes and the push notifications won't wake it up. is it possible to do so ? 
(Case study from a different platfom - facebook application not running but push can activate it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Services from Android.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private Timer timer;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomethingInBackground
    }, 0, 1000);
}
}
```

[The Android Dev Guide has a lot of samples and tutorials about services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)

Comment: so i should move my methods for starting the receivers to the service class? thanx for the reply!!!

Comment: You can also start an Activity from your Service or display a notification at the status bar of the phone.

Comment: when a notification comes , the status bar shows it has arrived , but i what my app to show it in a dialog with Yes/No buttons. which means i need my app to come to the foreground to do so.

Comment: To get the app(the Activity) in the foreground have a look at this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3607934/1031556)

Comment: i have started the registration for notification in the service , which was started in the activity. now if i try to get an alert out when the message arrives - it crashes : either babToken - no window in the service , or the activity doesnt exists and it is null.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to C2DM Google solution.

http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/android/c2dm/

Comment: i have , as mentioned in comments for previous answers :-) thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Android can close your app anytime it gets hibernated if it needs the memory. You can probably do what you're asking with a service.

Also: [Push Notifications in Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)

Comment: i wish not to use mqtt , i implemented c2dm as shown with a registration reciever and message reciever . i can see in the emulator that the notification arrives on the top bar , but pressing it shows an empty screen and when the message gets in , the app isn't being activated. i have inserted logs to see the calls of methods and i see it is being closed every time i press the "Back" button in the emulator. is their a way to keep it alive so when a message gets in , i can see my app/dialog box ?