# C2DM with Android 2.2 non-market devices

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, android-c2dm

I've signed up for Urban Airship and went through all of the tutorials and setup for C2DM but now realizing one thing - there seems to be a requirement of the Android Market on the device and an existing Google Account (http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)

This is a problem for me as the app is not to be delivered through the Market but through a pre-installed application on the KYROS MID7024 which is running Android 2.2 - we're planning to use this device exclusively so I really just need to know whether or not C2DM can be used outside of the market.

Looked all over the web, found some posts that were close but the fact that I will not be releasing my app in the market, solely on non-market devices I'm not having luck finding out if this is possible.

According to google docs for C2DM it says you can't..but is there anybody out there that's had any luck?  Any other ideas for simple push notification platform to deliver messages to non-market tablets? I'm not tied to UA at all just like the model and documentation so far.

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitively, authoritatively, trust me on this, C2DM won't work without Android Market.

From surfing around similar questions, came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform), which indicates your best bet would be MQTT.

Comment: Thanks a ton Alexander.  Will check that out.

Comment: If you want to pay for premium urban airship, they have a service called 'hellium' that can send push notifications to non-2.2 google market enabled devices iirc

Answer (score 1):

[Pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/) is another option you can consider for push notifications. It supports a myriad of platforms (including Android/iOS) and they have a generous enough free mode to get you going.

And yes, it will work across *all* Android versions and it does *not* need Android Market to be installed on the device.

Comment: It can't scale! If you have a large number of users for one app (100,000+) pubnub won't work as it can only handle 250 connections. It's not a serious alternative IMO