# How Live Stock Update or Live (Cricket) score update Android application works?

Tags: android, client-server

I want to know that how Live Stock Update or Live (Cricket) score update Android application works? Is Server connecting to client(Application) or client(Application) connecting to server?

Comment: What has this got to do with WCF???

Comment: Yes Hugh, You are right. WCF is not related to this. I have added this tag as my server is (will) running WCF and hence I put it subconsciously.

Comment: Thanks - have removed downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physically it's the client that connects to the server because mobile phones doesn't have static IPs or names that a server can use to connect.

But functionally that type of applications are usually implemented using PUSH notifications that simulate server to client communication.
You can look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform) or [here](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) for some information

Comment: Thanks Lujop, Here my doubt is how safe my data as in PUSH Notification we are pushing data through Google Server?

Comment: Normally you put very little data on push notification. And what you include is a key for the client that then it can use to query the server for the content of the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Can be both ways depending on type of feeds that you want to give

1. Device Connects.

You can use a service in background that connects to server and gets data after a fixed interval of time using [AlarmManagers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)/[Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) etc.

1. Server connects

You can use [c2DM](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Farticles%2FAndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging%2Farticle.html&ei=B2SeT-rXO4TkrAeLrcxO&usg=AFQjCNE2tjLs0kanqB98Qh_t1OVVcuwRmw&sig2=aXPeM1O1rneg5zFV8nSdLg)  where in you can force notification on devices.