# Notify whenever Rss file is changed android

Tags: android, service, rss

I create a simple to get news at dantri.com.vn,my project working properly, but I want to notify to user whenever dantri.com.vn have new news,(I think rss file is changed),how can I do that? 
Can you give me some ideals,thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Go For PushNotification

It will allow you to push your news update to device.
Once Notified your client app can fetch all the updated data

Check the answer below

[Push Notifications in Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)

Comment: @TungCan if it helps accept the answer by checking right arrow on the left side of answer