# How to implement push-notifications on Android?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, push

I have a website which supports Push-notifications, but what i must do to receive thhis notifications in my app?

Comment: repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform - Please search before asking.

Comment: [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform/20279735#20279735) I have posted solution, For Push Notification Implementation,May help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Googles Android Cloud to Device Messaging](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/). This also C2DM called funcionality enables you to push short messages to Android Devices. These short messages typically do not contain the actual data but only a code for "there is something available". In a next step, your application pulls the actual data from your server.

You can find a lot of usefull information by searching for [c2dm](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) here on StackOverflow. Also see [this very usefull tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

For implementng Push-notifications in your app you need to use [Cloud to Device messaging](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) or short C2DM

here some  tutorial for implementing C2DM in Application:

[Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

[Android Cloud To Device Messaging](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Push Notifications You need a sever side, that will manage your push subscriptions and send pushes to your user base.

Look at [Simple guide how to integrate Android Push Notifications](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/push-notifications), it's easy to integrate Push Notifications into your app using this guide, just add some lines of code.