# android transaction notification from webserver

Tags: php, android

I have made a website about online shopping, I want each transaction order provide alarm notification to my android application. What is needed to make this and how to get started?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

The keywords are "android push notifications".

If publishing only on GooglePlay, their official API is what you need.

Otherwise, consider alternatives, e.g., here:
[Push Notifications in Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)