# Status bar notification whenever new data is available

Tags: android, notifications

I have wondered a lot on Internet. At last, here I am gonna ask for help from you guys :

I am working on an Android Application in which I have to inform user through "**Status Bar Notification**" whenever new data is available on my web server.

I have thought of running a service on the Android Device and continuously ping on web server in order to find whether new data is available.

Please suggest, is this the way to do this or there is another better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is sometimes called [push notification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service). which on android devices is usually implemented using the new [google cloud messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

you use this to notify your android app that your server has new data, then get it from your server.

you may also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform) that is also about push notifications in android.