# IBM Worklight - How to Setup Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight for my Android App. What steps must I take to use Push Notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start by reading

- The [IBM Worklight Getting Started](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/) [Push Notifications training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf) and
- [IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp)'s [push-related articles](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_push_notification.html). You then
- familiarize yourself with the push-related API methods ([client](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_mobile_push_notification_metho.html), [server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/c_server_side_api.html)) and then
- You either try to create a sample app yourself and/or review the [supplied sample app](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/PushNotificationsProject.zip) prior to creating yours

There is no magic bullet.
If you then have a **technical** question while trying to implement push notifications, please open a new question.