# ANDROID: Call method every five minutes

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

How can i to run a method check() in every five minutes?
I want to check every five minutes have we new data or not, if is new data, then show notification

methods:

```
private void startAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, when, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES), pendingIntent);
}

public boolean isOnline(){
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      if(netinfo ==null || !netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
          return false;

      return true;
}

public void check(){
    if(isOnline())
    {
        //show notification if we have new data
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea - it will kill the battery.

Comment: then check every 10 minutes

Comment: every 10 minutes app will check access to internet, if (access == true){
just test have we new data or not, if have - then show notification}

Comment: AlarmManager are dangerous to the battery if not uses correctly... you want to check every 5 min only if he is using the app?

Comment: I agree with @SevaAlekseyev, 5 or 10 min it will kill the battery. Anyway, if you want to try, I suggest to use a Timer to start a TimerTask that will invoke your method. This will work only when app is open.

Comment: You can use handlers with post delayed.

Comment: omg )) i don't know what to do.
i want just to know site have new data or not

Comment: thanks for TimerTask, i'll to use it ))

Comment: Realistically, how often are you expecting new data for an average user? Every 5 minutes? Consider push notifications from the site.

Comment: I am with @Seva Alekseyev on push notifications, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform