# Property data is not updated accordingly as compared to data in the web

Tags: java, android, refresh

Issue:

To fully summarise the functionality of the app is; the application consists both web and mobile environment. However, the PROPERTY data that has been updated in the web version is not updated continuously within the mobile environment, hence, the PROPERTY data that the user access is always outdated. The PROPERTY data will only be updated when the user starts/restarts the application.

The PROPERTY data that has been initially downloaded when the user startup the app is stored within the apps local file directory [SQlite], and the activity will constantly point to the file directory to retrieve the dataId; which is not the updated PROPERTY data as compared to the PROPERTY data within the web environment.

Therefore, I would like to ask: How will I be able to enable the PROPERTY data to updated accordingly with the updated version in the web.

I was planning to use SyncAdapter method & Refresh button method to allow user to refresh and view the updated version. Any suggestions?

Comment: try a using Service and use timer task to initiate a listener to your server or webservice and set a notification for updated property.. do i good to you??

Comment: @Elltz I am currently using AsyncTask to do the property update, I actually have the refresh button setup to complement with the functionality of the AsyncTask.

Comment: yes @Ernest  Lee,  and im like create a service class which runs in d background.. let d service class run d async task every(duration)..to check for updates, if true-(meanin there are updates)- create a notification using notificationcombat tellin d user to update, when user clicks d notification d updates initiates- dats d logic let me knw if u want me to write codes..

Comment: @Elltz I will post the code up in a new question thread,have a look. I am not able to call the refresh button for user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Push Notifications API to notify users of updated property pages?

[Push Notifications in Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)

Comment: I understand that Android PUSH notifications generally uses Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) or uses Parse Cloud. That would mean I will have to change the entire structure of how my datas are stored.

Comment: Disagree? I don't mean push the property pages, I mean push a notification that there is an update and update using your system as appropriate. GCM isn't intended for massive data transfers anyway.

Comment: okay!!so you are referring to have an alert dialog to inform user of an update, which prompts for the user to download the latest property pages?

Comment: That is precisely what I meant!

Comment: Got it!!Thanks!I would like to further ask, how would you actually go about with the creation of the prompt command that link the push notification to the download service? I would assume that within the alert dialog button; there will be 2 options: Download latest version & Not Now, Thanks. How would you link the alertdialog to the download service?

Comment: I wouldn't. The alert should simply do like any other, bring up the application/activity and trigger your app to goto the update property section... No sense changing all that much.