# Push Notification on My app?

Tags: android, push-notification

Hi everyone I am developing an **University Android app** and in that I have *announcements section* where if any **announcement/notice** appear from the university it has to be updated and send it via **push notification** to the end users.

Would anyone suggest me the best way to do it.

Comment: @war_Hero can you give an example how to implement it, because I am not using any server right now.

Comment: go to parse.com create an account they have sample apps there

Comment: No problem glad i was helpful happy coding to you my friend

Comment: There are more solutions out there than just parse -- you should decide for yourself which is best.  Google Cloud Messaging, Amazon, UrbanAirship.  See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23181231/878159

Comment: Also duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform

Comment: @war_Hero can you say me how to add a notification in parse.com

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use parse.com for sending notifications easily and with very less code. First create accound in parse.com, next set up parse.com sdk in app, use this [link](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing).

There are two ways to send push notifications using Parse: channels and advanced targeting.Sending notifications is often done from the Parse.com push console, the REST API or from Cloud Code.

The simplest way to start sending notifications is using channels. This allows you to use a publisher-subscriber model for sending pushes. Devices start by subscribing to one or more channels, and notifications can later be sent to these subscribers. For eg:- A channel "new books in library" will give notification to only those who have subscribed to this channel.

A channel is identified by a string that starts with a letter and consists of alphanumeric characters, underscores, and dashes.

Subscribing to a channel can be done using a single method call. For example, in a university app, we could do:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("newbooks");
```

Sending Push from android SDK:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel("newbooks");
push.setMessage("Library has just received collection of Twilight series. Check it out!!");
push.sendInBackground();
```

If you want to send it to every users of your app then just go to the webpage and select push and click "send notification: [image]

Complete guide to get you going [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide).

Comment: @ranjith the above code should be put in mainactivity?

Comment: Ya you can put it in mainActivity or let user select the subscriptions user wants on screen. You need to go over the guide first to know the basics