# I want to send push notification from one android device to another using my application by Parse.com.

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to make an app where one user can ask for help and all other using this app will get that notification. I am using Parse.com for this as server. i am totally new to this please help me.I got registered my device by key etc. now i can send push notification from parse.com to my device.

but don't know how to make this on my device to send this to other devices?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This question is too broad to answer here, please get started on your own, then come back with a more specific question.  This question may be a good place to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create subscribe devices to different unique channel names, then you can send notification containing required payload to the device using the channel to which other device is subscribed.

```
//subscribing to channel

ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Channel_Name"); 

//getting installed devices
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
//query for getting devices with channel name
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", "Channel_Name"); 

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery);
push.setMessage("Your message payload");
push.sendInBackground();
```

You can subscribe multiple devices to same channel, but in this case when notification is send , it will be sent to all devices subscribed to a particular channel.

For more info: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications