# not receive push for android

Tags: android, push

I am testing an apps. Push notification is working fine in our server environment. But in client's environment, large amount of Android devices (NOT ALL) do not receive any push notification.

What is the possible factor? the return status form GCM is  "Failed"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push Notifications in Android Platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)

Answer (score 0):

> the return status from GCM is "Failed"

Android Device which is Receiving push must be online, if not GCM will pool notifications till it reached a mark of 100, It will start clearing the pool if more notification arrives at their end

> large amount of Android devices (NOT ALL) do not receive any push notification.

Did you check you have correct GCM ID with each device? If not The device will never receive a single notification. If your device have a valid GCM ID and have received some notification then it must be a problem in connecting with the device.

Also device must have Latest Play Services installed to get the notification on board

Comment: thanks for yr ans

what do you mean by ":online"? That's means the mobile has internet connection, right?

then wt's the factor affecting connection with device?

Comment: Maybe yes, If your device doesn't have connection for even a second when the notification arrived that will make a problem there