# Implementing status update for android

Tags: java, php, android

I am developing an android application that is connected to a restful API.

There is a challenging situation that the user of the app changes a setting on the website that should be changed on the android app too...

but I don't know how to notify the android app about the recent change made on the server.

can you help me solve this problem?
I was thinking about a push notification. is it a good practice to do so?

thank you for your time...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `Google Cloud Messaging` to send a push notification, another way is occasionally poll server for updates. Obviously first way is better because GCM batches that polling for all apps that use it => less battery drain etc.

In your case you probably also want to poll server for settings right before showing them in the app.