# Notification webview?

Tags: android, webview, notifications, android-webview, android-notifications

Next, I wanted to shoot a notification on my app when I post content on my site, does anyone know how to do it? Because I lose myself when I study in other sites. I want to get right on that part.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about [push notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)? If so, I think this question's already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform).