# Android Background processing even after process has stopped explicitly by user (Long pressing home button and deleting all recent apps)

Tags: android, service, background, background-process

I am newbie to android. I am creating file sharing application. When user1 asks to user2 for file, user2 will get notification and further upload and download process will execute.

Question:
**How can I implement such task which will keep track about some one has asked for file? I have created database in which entry will be done when someone asks for file. But how android device can constantly check that entry?**

I want such mechanism which is used by gmail to check every time for email. When mail comes, it shows notification.

Please help me to create such a background processing. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think gmail uses push notifications (but that requires a server to send them) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform  You could use AlarmManager to wake up something that checks.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer. I will have to use Google FCM push notification. I was unaware about that before. At last I found solution. Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a Service.

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background, and it does not provide a user
>   interface. Another application component can start a service, and it
>   continues to run in the background even if the user switches to
>   another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service
>   to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC).
>   For example, a service can handle network transactions, play music,
>   perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the
>   background.

Read more about services [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: I have already created services but it gets stopped when I clear background process explicitly by pressing long press on home button and removing all apps. I checked that by making process clear, Gmail's background process doesn't stop at all.