# Android custom notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-custom-view

How to make a custom notification the like a picture attachment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfs1o.png)
Do you have any suggest or idea for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push Notifications in Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RemoteViews` for this

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.YOUR_IMAGEVIEW_ID, YOUR_ICON);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW_ID, YOUR_NOTIFICAITON_TEXT);
```

You can add more parameters and customize it more, you have to read the [`RemoveViews` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews).

Then you create a `NotificationCompat.Builder` and add `contentView` as a `content` from `NotificationCompat.Builder` something like this :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(YOUR_CONTEXT)
.setContent(contentView);
```

Then create the `Notification`

```
Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(1, mNotification);
```

Those are the simple steps, now you can adjust it to your liking.

Also you can see this example on [`YouTube`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g97m0mgLXI) or this [`Tutorial`](http://code.hootsuite.com/custom-notifications-for-android/)