# I want to send push notification to specific users using PHP and gcm

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working on an Android project.
In that I need to send some notifications on background on the basis of condition on MySQL database...
How can I use PHP to send notification to certain users after checking the condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push Notifications in Android Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to achieve this,

1. Get the device token using Firebase SDK and store it in your mysql database against user (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)
2. Select device tokens matching your criteria (SQL Query)
3. Send the push message to selected device using firebase rest api (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send,  [How can I send a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification without use the Firebase Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase))