# push notification in Android 1.6

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to know that is it possible to implement the push notification in Android 1.6. If it possible then how can I solve this?

Comment: Title-version is different from text-version...

Comment: sorry for that actually i want that is it possible to implement push notification in android 1.6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Android support near real time push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible using MQTT Library [use this url](http://mqtt.org/) use this website to [learn more](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/) if you don't get it give me your mail i'll give you this.

Comment: thank you ,but the push message page is offline,  http://tokudu.com/demo/android-push/  can you put it on line?

Comment: MqttException: NULL, can you tell me  why? i not modify the resource

Comment: can you tell me  in the link http://tokudu.com/demo/android-push/,the two editView, i should what write to input

Comment: Download android application through [this link](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/) start this and you can see `Your Device Target:xxxxxxxxxx` in your application screen this code is enter in first textbox and in 2nd your message and than press send button.

Comment: yes, i enter these but give me INFO/DemoPushService(2410): Rescheduling connection in 1800000ms.
 INFO/DemoPushService(2410): Connectivity changed: connected=true
 INFO/DemoPushService(2410): Reconnecting...
 INFO/DemoPushService(2410): Connecting...
09-05 19:47:50.623: INFO/DemoPushService(2410): MqttException: NULL
09-05 19:47:50.623: INFO/DemoPushService(2410): Rescheduling connection in 1800000ms.

Comment: That's not the reason but currently server is offline just check and whenever is online test this.