# push notification in android 1.6

Tags: push-notification

Is it possible to implement the push notification in android 1.6? If it is possible then how can I implement this in my Android apps?

Comment: You should just edit your previous question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [push notification in android 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437568/push-notification-in-android-1-5)

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship just opened up our public beta of [Push for Android](http://urbanairship.com/docs/android_push.html), which provides Push support for Android 1.5+.

Full disclosure: I work for Urban Airship.

Comment: It is possible to use Android C2DM as a delivery mechanism for UrbanAirship, but the mobile device must have Android 2.2 or higher to receive C2DM messages.