# How to PUSH a notification from my server to my Android App?

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to control PUSH notification own, without using third party server like for C2MD need to PUSH notification through Google server. So there is any idea, How can i achieve this for Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a persistent TCP/IP connection for achieving this.

Some resources for your reference

http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

http://mqtt.org

Seems stackoverflow has discussion on it

[Does Android support near real time push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification)

Comment: I have gone through it before and not found information which i am looking for :(

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if it answers your question but have you considered xmpp?
Or  this
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html
similar topic
[Does Android support near real time push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification)