# Background service in Sencha touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am building an mobile app ( RSS reader ) for Android with Sencha touch and PhoneGap. I have created some sort of background service that checks every 12 hours for new posts and update the app. When there is a new post a notification is shown up ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html )

I am using window.setInterval() for this. This seems like a dirty way to do it, but it works.

Whats your opinion about this and is there a better way to get the job done?

Comment: You may want to read through this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other way, in JS, to do it would be a [long poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling) with an XHR request.  The notifications can then be pushed when they show up instead of every 12 hrs.  However this probably isn't a great solution as it will tie up server resources and require a constant connection.

Because you are also using PhoneGap, you could write a [plugin for Android](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How-to-Create-a-PhoneGap-Plugin-for-Android) that will implement a JS object with the ability to register callbacks for and call them at a particular time. Or implement the API that @ballmw suggested.

In the end, setTimeout/setInterval is probably fine if it works properly.