# Building my own push notification server to client (NOT PHONE APP)

Tags: php

I have been reading on push notifications. I know apple and google for their phones, call it two different things. There are a lot of posts on stack over flow about the services google and apple offer for their phones like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560246/how-to-add-a-push-notification-in-my-own-android-app).

Reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) makes me curious if this is even possible. It is basically saying that there is no straight forward way of doing this other than just keeping a connection open instead of closing it. It mentions some new standards that are heading in that direction though.

I have a php server api. Currently it is setup for the client side to use HTTP GET to see if there are any updates. I though since 90% of the time there are no updates wouldn't I save a lot of taxing on my MySQL server if I used an HTTP PUSH when there is an update instead of constantly checking for updates.

If this is possible in PHP and someone knows of a tutorial on it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having your server write to a file when there is an update noting the last update time;  and then when the page loads, it checks for that file and looks at the last update time.  If that time is later than {cookie-value} then it proceeds on to the mySql part of the code, if not it doesn't.

Not exactly a push, but it does save your MySQL work.  How feasible it is depends on what sort of updates you have and how much control you have over the update task itself, of course.

Comment: That is a great work around idea! My problem is I am thinking of scalability. If I have 1,000 devices checking every minute for their own individual file then that will tax the server. Every client is looking for an individual update. I guess if there are no other options taxing the server in that way is a ton better than doing the  MySQL query.

Comment: @mark Instead of a file you could use memcache, it will let you use the memory instead.

Comment: Well, how about writing to a single file name / update time?  Then you just have to parse for the client's UID, which a regex can find pretty easily.  Not sure how that would compare to a thousand files, but another option.

Comment: @Alex thats better and FASTER than the file. (Joe) and if I use your idea it only goes through the list of customers with updates pending. Thanks for the options. If no one else answers with a true push option I will keep this check mark for the answer above.