# send notification to specific android device by my website

Tags: android, push-notification, android-service

am new to push notification and services in android. I want to send request through my own website and I want that the service running at my android device should read this request. Is there any way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Look into GCM. Google Cloud Messaging. Your server, with data to sens to the app, sends a request to the GCM api, a small packet goes to ypur device. and your device says okay, lets fetch from our server.

Comment: I've read this documentation but couldn't found anything that i was looking for. I want to send request from my own website to a specific android device by using device id.

Comment: Your server does not have active connections open with all of the apps, so you can not send a message directly to the device, called a push notification. A Get notification is when your device periodically polls the server at scheduled intervals, and chacks for new data, if so, download. GCM takes a request from your server, and sends it to the device specified. The device specified is alerted there is data available, and it will then Get data from the server.

Comment: Thanks Matt! you should write this as answer so that I could mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use GCM to have push notifications
Refer this: [Android "hello world" pushnotification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386392/android-hello-world-pushnotification-example)

This may help too: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you mean.
If you want to send requests to your website using android you could use Apache's DefaultHttpClient.

Here is an example:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

The above code is a Get request to the image_of_the_dat.rss file from the nasa website

Comment: in your case you'll get the response to your android device when you'll send request to server. But I want to send request to device from my server/website.