# Web service in android for sending and receiving

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing an android app and I want to make the app to send request to other devices having same app.  The receiver app should get request notification as like we get in Facebook.  Which web service/method should I call from request ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android "hello world" pushnotification example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386392/android-hello-world-pushnotification-example)

Comment: try to make the sentences a little better.  fixed some typos