# Model to implement push notifications for users which are different for each notification in Titanium

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, titanium, titanium-modules

I want to implement notifications for my android app(Titanium framework) but I am not sure on how to implement.
I have a lms website. If a faculty creates an assignment in a course, all the students of that course has to get notifications.

I want to do it in the below way:

1. I will collect the device tokens and map with the student id when a student login in my app(lms) from the device
2. I will send a notifications to all device id's of students in the respective course

Is it a right way to do it?
Also I am confused about device id vs user session based notifications in Titanium. Can you please tell me which one I should use in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

- Official documentation from Google:
  https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
- [Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
- Similar question on Stack Overflow [How to add a push notification in my own android app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12560246/4152581)