# Loading external Content for hybrid Apps in Native App Container (Android, IOS)

Tags: android, ios, css, html, hybrid

i want to create Content in HTML5 CSS JS and want to run it on mobile devices.

And now the requirements:
There is the device with a container (native app) where i can load the created content (HTML CSS JS ...) from a Server. And every time when i change the content on the Server the App tells me sth. like "u have to update the content"

I know there are a lot of frameworks etc. 
Did anybody knows if there is a solution for my requirements?

greetz

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display created content(HTML CSS JS ...) from server and need to implement [Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560246/how-to-add-a-push-notification-in-my-own-android-app) to show the message in app when you update the content from server