# how to display dialog over other application instead of stopping other activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, dialog

What my application actually should do is, it should open a dialog box over
other application say like Whatsapp's text from notification feature like it opens a window over any application like that. Here is my code. It closes an running application and opens the dialog box so what i actually need is the other running application am using should not get closed instead the dialog should open over them.

How my application actually works

- MainActivity starts and press the start button
- MainActivity closes and the notification is appeared
- Click the notification, dialog box appears press add to count the no.(Here it closes the running application say if I'm using FB app)
- To finish the process press quit in the notification

How I need it to work is

- When i click the notification the dialog box should open over the other application the running application should not get closed it should remain still

Help me out guys, Thanks in advance.
Suggest me if any other ways to implement this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button start;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        NotificationClass notification = new NotificationClass(MainActivity.this);
            notification.showNotification("Floating app","Started");
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

NotificationClass.java

```
public class NotificationClass {
    Context mContext;
    static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 111;

NotificationClass(Context context){

    mContext = context;
}

void showNotification(String title,String message)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name).setOngoing(true).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message);
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(mContext,WorkSpace.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(activityIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(123,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    //

    Intent resultIntent =  new Intent(mContext,ResultActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,456,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_cancel,"Quit",resultPendingIntent);




    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

}

void cancelNotification(){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
}
```

ResultActivity.java

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvResult;
SharedPreferences sp;
String PRESENT = "isPresent";
String COUNT = "getCount";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    NotificationClass notificationClass = new NotificationClass(this);
    notificationClass.cancelNotification();
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String msg = "Total Count:"+sp.getInt(COUNT,-3);
    tvResult.setText(msg);
    resetCount();

}

private void resetCount() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(PRESENT,false);
    editor.putInt(COUNT,0);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

WorkSpace.java

```
public class WorkSpace extends AppCompatActivity {

String TAG = "WorkSpace";
TextView tvCount;
Button btAdd;
Integer count;
SharedPreferences sp;
String PRESENT = "isPresent";
String COUNT = "getCount";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG,"Created");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_space);

    tvCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
    btAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

}

public void addCount(View v){
    count++;
    updateCount();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG,"Paused");
    storeCount();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG,"Resumed");
    if(sp.getBoolean(PRESENT,false)){
        count = sp.getInt(COUNT,-1);
    }else{
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PRESENT,true);
        editor.putInt(COUNT,0);
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();
        count = sp.getInt(COUNT,-2);

    }
    updateCount();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG,"Destroyed");
}


private void updateCount() {
    String msg = "Count:"+count;
    tvCount.setText(msg);
}

private void storeCount() {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt(COUNT,count);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.kewldevs.sathish.floatapps.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_result.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.kewldevs.sathish.floatapps.ResultActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Result"
    android:id="@+id/tvResult"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_work_space.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.kewldevs.sathish.floatapps.WorkSpace"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvCount"
    android:gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/btAdd"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:onClick="addCount" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ResultActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".WorkSpace"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

The functionality you are looking for is called push notifications. There are two ways to do this, generally; 1. Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), which does lots of things including push, the method to do so can be found in this older post: [How to add a push notification in my own android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560246/how-to-add-a-push-notification-in-my-own-android-app), or 2. Parse, which is a library that functions like GCM for push notifications but is a bit easier to set-up: https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: could you please read my post once again. Your solution is irrelevant to my question

Comment: No you don't understand; you can not display a dialog over another application. What you believe to be a dialog box over another application such as like WhatsApp or Facebook or w/e, is actually a push notification. They're completely different constructs, and to achieve a push notification, you need to implement it in 1 of 2 ways as I outlined above.

Comment: What I think you're looking for is the addAction functionality in the NotificationBuilder. I think you still need to integrate GCM, not 100% sure, but you can eventually modify that Builder with those add actions which should provide the functionality you're searching for.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction%28android.app.Notification.Action%29 for details