# Send android app a message?

Tags: android

is there a way to send aandroid a ring method or vibrate method via http??

If so how does anyone have any information on it how to do this?

Comment: Qusetion is too broad, lacking in detail and not a specific programming question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification

Comment: http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you need it C2DM (cloud to device messaging)

Here's a couple of links (in the order I suggest you to read):

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html
- http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/
- http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/
- google :)