# Is there any push notification service in Android like Apple Push Notification Service?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I want to provide a push notification service to Android phone users, is there any push notification service in Android like Apple Push Notification Service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Android support near real time push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh yes! Its called [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/). Do check it out!

Edit: [Tutorial](http://neevtech.com/blog/?p=131) link added!

Edit: For completeness, C2DM has now been deprecated in favor of [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)

Edit: GCM has now been replaced by [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: This cloud-based push service meets my requirements. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have any hands-on experience in C2DM ?

Comment: I just wanted to implement it in one of my apps. I have registered for the service, which will allow me to send messages from the Google Server, but I haven't got around to actually implementing it. So in short, I don't have much hands-on experience, but yea, I know the theoretical part.

Comment: But I think there will be a lot of tutorials available and also a whole lot of posts here on SO! So good luck.

Comment: Hi, I have gone through the C2DM documentation, it seems that it uses a ClientLogin token during the message sending process. The client login phase involves CAPTCHA challenge. If the message is sent by application server automatically, how the server do the login phase with CAPTCHA challenge ?

Comment: @AnandSainath let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2346/discussion-between-user403015-and-anand-sainath)

Comment: It seems that C2DM has been discontinued and been replaced by Google Cloud Messaging for Android : http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging has now been replaced by Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: I attended Google IO this year and I think Firebase is something that is going to be talked about for some time now. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) Google Cloud Messaging for Android

Comment: Thanks Dhiral, yeah this seems to be the replacement of C2DM (mentioned in edit to answer)

Answer (score 0):

> [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is the new version of [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features.

Reference: [GCM and FCM frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq)