# Android - Update UI to all clients in multiplayer game?

Tags: android, json, servlets, multiplayer

I am currently developing a multiplayer card game, using simple servlets with the Android device sending JSON back and forth. I am currently confused on how to tell all other clients that a certain player has submitted a card, so that they all can update their UI.

What are the options for me to do so?
I am currently thinking of several options:

1. Fetch from a MOVE_TABLE from database every x ms. (with specific room IDs and live room sessions).
2. Let the servlet send a certain 'broadcast' to the respected clients in the room each time a certain player do something, so that the other clients don't have to do a GET or POST every x ms. (although I don't know how to do this,  it's just my thinking).

Can anybody help me? Or maybe suggest me a better solution? Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Option 2 is probably the "best", though how to do it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will using this type of solution work for you? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

I found it at this question if you want some more info:
[Does Android support near real time push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification)

If this would cause a massive architecture change to send the move as a notification, then may I suggest just using the push notification as a hint for the game to perform a new MOVE_TABLE query or whatever you need to do to get the new move.

Comment: from the link: It uses existing connections for Google services. This requires the users to sign into their Google account on Android.
I cannot let my user sign in to their Google account just to play..I use my own LOGIN_TABLE..or should I pull this from the Accounts and Sync menu.. I don't think this option is quite favourable for me.. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: however, judging from some of the push technologies available now, I think I have to use C2DM T_T as I am running this on Windows..Deacon project seems promising but it seems it drains battery life

Comment: Yea sorry. I'm not too familiar with a simple way to get people to use their Google account. I would imagine its not a huge burden to the user if they are already logged in to get your app through the marketplace?

Comment: I have found a better solution. I have to use a socket-server, i.e. SmartFoxServer to suit my needs better. C2DM is not suitable for frequent message pushing, C2DM also does not guarantee the order the messages being pushed.