# What is the difference between androidpn connection to server and normal socket connection?

Tags: android, connection, push

As I know a long connection is power-consumed on mobile device, then androidpn is the same as normal connection on power consumption? So androidpn push only saves data flow instead of power?

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about writing efficient code when using the network take a look at the tools and resources available here http://developer.att.com/aro and http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=7200042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all implementations that provide a service based on XMPP for push notifications have the same battery drain on mobile.

In this response, you have an estimate of how much battery can consume a persistent TCP connection: [Does Android support near real time push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification)

For specific details would have to revise androidipn client code.

regards

Comment: Thanks. Your info is helpful. The power consumption is horrible to some extent.