# Sending notification to everyone running an application, Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

Set up:
I have a system which has multiple users. Each user will download my app onto their Android phone and use it. What I want is when any user performs a specific action (I have two in my app), I want to pop up a notification in all the other user phones.

A simple break down is like this:
Start app --> Navigate to the part where action is performed --> Perform the action --> Store the action the a DB --> Notify ALL USERS --> Pop up the same notification on all phones.

How would I go about this problem? Can anyone suggest ideas or links, cause I don't even have a clue on how to approach this.

Comment: GCM might work, and you will definitely need a dedicated server.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html Google Cloud Messaging. Supposed to be simple push messaging.

Comment: @A--C but it requires device registration. I always think of Facebook for android and how it works. Does FB actually register your phone? Because when you log into FB from a different phone, you will receive your own notifications.

Comment: Well FB has it's own dedicated login service and push mechanism :)

Comment: @Cartman : What you describe is a "push" notification requirement. The suggestion of GCM by A--C is a good one. There are alternatives such as Urban Airship and if you want to support the latest Kindle devices, Amazon have a beta push notification service.

Comment: Let me read about those and I will get back to you =) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to send notification to all users, even if all the users are not actively using the application, then Puch Notification is a good approach.

> Push notifications let your application notify a user of new messages
>   or events even when the user is not actively using your application.
>   On Android devices, when a device receives a push notification, your
>   application's icon and a message appear in the status bar. When the
>   user taps the notification, they are sent to your application.
>   Notifications can be broadcast to all users, such as for a marketing
>   campaign, or sent to just a subset of users, to give personalized
>   information.

Have a look at [Android Google Cloud Messaging](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Also I have found [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) a good solution as described by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5695867/1626878).

You will find some good solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need a database on a server, and then you will need the app to constantly (or at intervals) query the database in the background for changes, and notify the user when it finds one. A system similar to how many apps give notifications is what I am getting at.

Comment: Well, facebook and twitter and textmessages always seem to be received right away. I doubt they check it every second or at time intervals. Checking constantly is very battery draining and checking at intervals is not time efficient. What if it is urgent?