# How to make android await for incoming requests

Tags: android

Is that possible to make an android app await for incoming requests. Maybe my terminology is bad, but I need something like a server on android. Instead of sending requests to the server on and on to check if a status on the server changed, I want the server to send this information directly to my android app. I heard it's possible, but couldn't google it, maybe I used bad phrases...

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google advised way to do it is use [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html):

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device.

Try to look to [Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) / [Pull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) notification.

Related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification/)