# Android send notification message to device without client app installed on the device

Tags: android, ibeacon

I would like to know is there any way to send notification  from a server to an Android device without a client app installed on the device. Does android OS has such functionality. Based on the answer here [Does Android support near real time push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification/)  `Google Cloud Messaging` do similar things, but it seems the client app need to be installed on user mobile.

Basically what I want do when an android device comes in range of an [iBeacon](https://blog.pushmote.com/10-most-frequently-asked-questions-about-ibeacons.html)
I need to send the notification messages to the user mobile.

Is there any way to achieve it. Any possible solution?

**Edit:**

The real scenario is like, 
 I have the beacon placed in somewhere, when the a device comes in range of the beacon, some how I have to detect the device(if the device Bluetooth is on) and get some id of the device send notification from cloud server. Where as the device(Android phone) don't know the beacon is there, or there is no app installed on the device to detect the beacon.

I am not sure whether it's possible to achieve the above goal in such a scenario.

Please let me know your valuable feedback.

Comment: use `Enter` and `Exit region` the way of `IBeacons`. Why push notification ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?. Actually I need to send some custom message to user mobile with image and text.

Comment: what type of custom images you want to display? i mean server send this images.

Comment: Yes the image and message are stored on server database.

Comment: I have one way. Download all the data from your server and store it in your mobile DB. and when you are in the range of beacons create a custom notification with data and image and show it. No need to implement GCM in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome 42 or higher for Android supports [push notifications from websites](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en), which allows you to send notifications without installing an app.

If you're specifically looking to start notifications from a beacon, Chrome 49 added [support for beacons](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/the-physical-web-expands-to-chrome-for_10.html)

Comment: So which application is going to receive the notification on Android, google chrome?.

Comment: That's correct - Google Chrome receives the push notification, forwarding it to your Service Worker for display

Comment: Based on this link http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/20/8454613/push-notifications-android-chrome-42-mobile-web the user need to visit some site  that supports notifications, will receive a prompt asking you if you'd like to turn them on. When you do, that website can send you push notifications whether you have the browser open or not. That means I have to create site and user should visit that site and subscribe the notification. But I think it's not suit for above situation.

Comment: @Haris - see the updated answer - Chrome 49 added beacon support