# Can I send a local silent notification from a Widget?

Tags: android

I would like to pass some data from a Widget to an app, where I have some limitations:

- The WidgetProvider needs to start a service, which will process the intent
- When the MainActivity is in the background it works well
- The service dies if the user kills the app, therefore the Widget kill keep crashing and is no longer usable
- If the app is killed and I re-enable the Widget it will start the service in the background and it will work well

On the other side, my notification listener works perfectly fine. Is there a way to send a notification with pure data to the app? That way I would not need to care on the application lifecycle and process the notifications independently.

All these limitations are provided because I am a react-native developer, so this is a little bit tricky.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Android support near real time push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification)

Comment: Given the problem you have based on the characteristics of the app. Could you elaborate what these are?

Comment: Sure @RubenAalders, just edited!

Comment: @AbhishekCharismatic I just reviewed your link, it does not look like a duplicate